# Сортировка символов в массиве

Tags: алгоритм, строки, c++, сортировка

Вводится число, нужно путем перестановок его цифр получить минимальное.

Я реализовал, только у меня неправильно работает если в числе окажется 0.

Помогите реализовать, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void sort(string &s)
{
    for(int a = 1; a < s.length(); a++)
    {
        for(int b = s.length() - 1; b >= a; b--)
        {
            if(s[b-1] > s[b] && !(s[b] == '0' && b - 1 == 0))
                swap(s[b-1], s[b]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string a;

    cin >> a;

    sort(a);

    cout << a << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нули в начале запрещены, делайте так:

1. Отсортируйте цифры по возрастанию
2. Если в начале получился ноль, найдите первый не-ноль, и обменяйте его местами с первым нулём

Если первого не-нуля на втором шаге не нашлось, ваше число было 0, и значит, всё и так в порядке.

Comment: точно, спасибо

Comment: @risonyo: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае очень подходит метод сортировки пузырьком. Далее привожу пример:

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;
        // наш массив
        int array[100];
        // сортировка
        void*Sort(int col) 
        { 
            // временная переменная для хранения промежуточного результата
            int trash=0;  
            // пока не равно количеству елементов
            for (int i=1; i<=col ; i++)
            {
                // пока не равно col-i
                for (int j=1; j<=col-i; j++) 
                {
                    // если левый элемент больше
                    if (array [j]>array [j+1]) 
                    {
                        // правого, то меняем их местами
                        trash=array[j]; 
                        array [j]=array [j+1];
                        array [j+1]=trash;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // вывод на экран нашего массива после сортировки
        void*Out(int col) 
        {
            for (int i=1; i<=col; i++) 
            cout << array [i] <<" ";
            cout << endl; 
        }
        int main()
        {
            int col_el;
            cout << " Enter length of array"<< endl;
            // считываем количество элементов
            cin >> col_el;
            // считываем элементы массива
            for (int n=1; n<=col_el ; n++) 
            cin >> array[n];
            Sort(col_el); 
            // сортируем их
            cout << "Result is :"<<endl; 
            // и выводим  
            Out(col_el);
            // ждем нажатия клавиши
            cin >> col_el; 
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Я думаю, ТС знает, как сортировать пузырьком. Проблема была в начальных нулях.